# Implementing sanitize simple_format in rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sanitization, sanitize

I have created an application that allows for users to input lots of different data (posts, comments, etc.). The simple_format is good for me for now I just want to protect against crazy stuff. I haven't used sanitize before and after reading some guides I am still a little confused on how to implement. Hoping I can get some direction here.

Let's say I am collecting @post.body. How do I remove any `<div`> tags or `<script>` tags that might be entered by the user? I am assuming that in the view it would look something like this:

```
<%= sanatize(simple_format @post.body) %>
```

...but where do I define what tags aren't allowed? In the Post model or in a sanitize_helper? What is the correct syntax here?

Comment: That "sanatize" typo is hilarious lol!! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the documentation link for the [sanitize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#M002153) method in Rails 2.3.8. With that in mind you'll be able to define allowed tags in this way:

```
<%= sanitize(simple_format(@post.body), :tags => %w(p span strong)) %>
```

Note that you can define them also inside the Rails Initializer:

```
  Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
    config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_tags = 'table', 'tr', 'td'
  end
```

I hope you find this helpful!